# why pointers when assign it using value does't appear same result using address?

Tags: c++

why first statement ptr->show() displayed base although i assign *ptr = dv1
but second statement ptr->show() displayed Derv2 i expected first display Derv1 and two display Derv2

```
class Base {

    public:

    virtual void show() 

    {

    cout << "Base\n";
    }
 };


class Derv1 : public Base //derived class 1
{

  public:

    void show()
    {
        cout << "Derv1\n";
    }
};

class Derv2 : public Base 
{
  public:
    void show()
    {
        cout << "Derv2\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
  Derv1 dv1; //object of derived class 1
  Derv2 dv2; //object of derived class 2
  Base* ptr = new Base(); //pointer to base class
  *ptr = dv1; //put value of dv1 in pointer
  ptr->show(); //execute show()
  ptr = &dv2; //put address of dv2 in pointer
  ptr->show(); //execute show()
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `*ptr = dv1; //put address of dv1 in pointer` Nope, the code doesn't do what the comment says it does.

Answer (score 0):

`*ptr = dv1; //put address of dv1 in pointer`

This code creates a copy of `Base` from `dv1` and copies into `ptr` which is still of type `Base`.

`ptr = &dv2; //put address of dv2 in pointer`

This code tells `ptr` to point to the address of `dv2` which is an object of type `Derv2`. Since `Base::show` is virtual, it correctly calls the `Derv2` implementation of `show`.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `*ptr = dv1` means that the `Derv1` class will be cast to a `base` class and thus output 'base'

This is because `*ptr` is dereferencing the pointer and effectively saying `base &`. As a result, the `Derv1` class can be easily cast to a `base &` as it inherits the class of `base`

---

However, `ptr = &dv2` means that it will point to the memory address of `dv2` and thus, when the function is called, it will come from `dv2` and thus output 'Derv2'

Comment: That first part is confused. `*ptr = dv1` means assign dv1 to the base at ptr. The compiler will do it's best to copy a Derv1 into a Base by treating the Derv1 as if it was a Base.